# How to collapse a pandas dataframe? (pivot table)

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
day_of_week   ice_cream     count   proportion
0   Friday    vanilla       638     0.094473
1   Friday    chocolate     2048    0.663506
2   Friday    strawberry    4088    0.251021
3   Monday    vanilla       448     0.079736
4   Monday    chocolate     2332    0.691437
5   Monday    strawberry    441     0.228828
6   Saturday  vanilla       24      0.073350
7   Saturday  chocolate     244     0.712930  ...   ...
```

I want a new DataFrame that collapses onto `day_of_week` as an index so it looks like this:

```
    day_of_week vanilla    chocolate   strawberry
0   Friday      0.094473   0.663506    0.251021 
1   Monday      0.079736   0.691437    0.228828
2   Saturday    ...        ...         ...
```

What's the cleanest way I can implement this?

Comment: Look up the pivot function on pandas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`df.pivot_table`](https://www.google.de/search?q=pandas%20pivot%20table&oq=pandas%20pivot%20table&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.3053j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is the correct solution:

```
In[31]: df.pivot_table(values='proportion', index='day_of_week', columns='ice_cream').reset_index()
Out[31]: 
    ice_cream day_of_week  chocolate  strawberry   vanilla
0              Friday   0.663506    0.251021  0.094473
1              Monday   0.691437    0.228828  0.079736
2            Saturday   0.712930         NaN  0.073350
```

If you leave out `reset_index()` it will actually return an indexed dataframe, which might be more useful for you.

Note that a pivot table necessarily performs a dimensionality reduction when the `values` column is not a function of the tuple `(index, columns)`. If there are multiple `(index, columns)` pairs with different `value` `pivot_table` brings the dimensionality down to one by using an aggregation function, by default `mean`.

Comment: `.reset_index()` to get the OP's desired output?

Comment: what would be the inverse of this function?

Comment: try stack and unstack

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for pivot_table

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='day_of_week', columns='ice_cream', values = 'proportion')
```

You get:

```
ice_cream   chocolate   strawberry  vanilla
day_of_week         
Friday      0.663506    0.251021    0.094473
Monday      0.691437    0.228828    0.079736
Saturday    0.712930    NaN         0.073350
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pivot table:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'day_of_week':['Friday','Sunday','Monday','Sunday','Friday','Friday'], \
'count':[200,300,100,50,110,90], 'ice_cream':['choco','vanilla','vanilla','choco','choco','straw'],\
'proportion':[.9,.1,.2,.3,.8,.4]})

print df

# If you like replace np.nan with zero
tab = pd.pivot_table(df,index='day_of_week',columns='ice_cream', values=['proportion'],fill_value=np.nan)
print tab
```

Output:

```
   count day_of_week ice_cream  proportion
0    200      Friday     choco         0.9
1    300      Sunday   vanilla         0.1
2    100      Monday   vanilla         0.2
3     50      Sunday     choco         0.3
4    110      Friday     choco         0.8
5     90      Friday     straw         0.4
            proportion              
ice_cream        choco straw vanilla
day_of_week                         
Friday            0.85   0.4     NaN
Monday             NaN   NaN     0.2
Sunday            0.30   NaN     0.1
```

Comment: Wow you actually took the time to create a DataFrame. You know that `pd.read_clipboard()` exists right?

Answer (score 1):

Using `set_index` and `unstack`

```
df.set_index(['day_of_week', 'ice_cream']).proportion.unstack() \
  .reset_index().rename_axis([None], 1)

  day_of_week  chocolate  strawberry   vanilla
0      Friday   0.663506    0.251021  0.094473
1      Monday   0.691437    0.228828  0.079736
2    Saturday   0.712930         NaN  0.073350
```

***timing vs `pivot_table`***

[image]